# I am facing problems while starting an activity using “startActivity()” from quicksetting tile service

Tags: java, android

I am facing problems while starting an activity using “startActivity()” from quicksetting tile service. I want to launch activities from my app as well as other installed apps.
Problem : If the app is open in foreground, it works as expected, while if it isn’t open(in background/recents or not running), then no activity launches.
Expected output : Activity should launch on clicking quick setting tile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`startActivityAndCollapse`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#startActivityAndCollapse(android.content.Intent)) from within your `TileService` to launch an Activity from your quick settings tile.

Otherwise, the [restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) will block your activity launch unless your activity is already in the foreground, as you experienced.

Comment: i have tried this as well , but still it is not working